# How do I skip values with no content?

Tags: python, excel, string, loops, directory

## How do I store the values with content into strings?

I know there has to be a much cleaner and more efficient way of doing this but currently I am struggling to find a way. I would appreciate a set of fresh eyes on this since I must be missing something. I have spent an outlandish time on this.

My objective is:
**Check if sheet.values has content -> if so, store as a string**

**Check if sheet.values has content -> if not, skip or create no string**

The priority of this is that sheet.values can contain an undetermined amount of content that needs to be identified. Such as sheet.values filled in being up to [9] one instance but being filled in to [6] another instance. So it needs to account for this.

**The sheet.values also have to return as a string as I use makedirs() later in the code (it gets a bit testy this also needs work if you can help)**

I know a for loop should be able to help me but just not found the right one just yet.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index

os. chdir("C:\\Users\\NAME\\desktop")
workbook = pd.ExcelFile('Example.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.parse('Sheet1')

print (sheet.values[0])

os.getcwd()
path = os.getcwd()


for input in sheet.values:
  if any(sheet.values): 
    if input == None:
      break

else:
  if any(sheet.values): 
    sheet.values == input
    set

str1 = '1'.join(sheet.values[0])
str2 = '2'.join(sheet.values[1])
str3 = '3'.join(sheet.values[2])
str4 = '4'.join(sheet.values[3])
str5 = '5'.join(sheet.values[4])
str6 = '6'.join(sheet.values[5])
str7 = '7'.join(sheet.values[6])
str8 = '8'.join(sheet.values[7])
str9 = '9'.join(sheet.values[8])
str10 = '10'.join(sheet.values[9])
str11 = '11'.join(sheet.values[10])
str12 = '12'.join(sheet.values[11])
str13 = '13'.join(sheet.values[12])
str14 = '14'.join(sheet.values[13])
str15 = '15'.join(sheet.values[14])
str16 = '16'.join(sheet.values[15])
str17 = '17'.join(sheet.values[16])
str18 = '18'.join(sheet.values[17])
str19 = '19'.join(sheet.values[18])
str20 = '20'.join(sheet.values[19])
str21 = '21'.join(sheet.values[20])

########################ONE################################################

try:

  if not os.path.exists(str1):

        os.makedirs(str1)

except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % str1)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % str1)

########################TWO################################################

try:
  if not os.path.exists(str2):

        os.makedirs(str2)

except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % str2)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % str2)


########################THREE################################################


try: 
  if not os.path.exists(str3):

        os.makedirs(str3)
except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % str3)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % str3)

########################FOUR################################################

try: 
  if not os.path.exists(str4):

        os.makedirs(str4)
except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % str4)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % str4)
```

`Note: The makedirs() code runs down till to the full amount of strings`

The Excel document shows the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4NN2.png)

This script results in: `index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9`
This is truthfully expected as the sheet.values only this amount.

Can anyone help me? I know it is messy

## Updated Code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index

os. chdir("C:\\Users\\NAME\\desktop")
workbook = pd.ExcelFile('Example.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.parse('Sheet1')

print (sheet.values[0])

os.getcwd()
path = os.getcwd()

print ("The current working Directory is %s" % path)

for col in sheet.values:
    for row in range(len(col)):
        dir_name = str(row + 1) + col[row]
        try:
        os.makedirs(dir_name, exist_ok=True)

except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % dir_name)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % dir_name)
```

Comment: the indentation is different from str9 on.

Comment: What is your suggestion on the best way to do that? because I know it needs to change alot. Also will do @j1-lee, sorry about this

Comment: Ah @randomer64 apologies. This was a mistake putting it into stack overflow. The script does not actually have that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you're trying to read the first column of a csv, and create directories based on the value.

```
with open(mypath+file) as file_name:
    file_read = csv.reader(file_name)
    file = list(file_read)

for col in file:
    for row in range(len(col)):
        dir_name = str(row + 1) + col[row]
        try:
            # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs
            os.makedirs(dir_name, exist_ok=True)
        except OSError:
            print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % str1)
        else:
            print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % str1)
```